# Entity Framework 'Add' function adds two objects instead of one

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with VB.NET.

The problem is that when I add a new 'user' object to the context, an additional user is added.

This is the code:

```
Dim Db As New DbModel

' Create a new user
Dim NewUser = New User With {
    .UserName = txtUserName.Text.Trim,
    .Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim,
    .Department = cmbDepartment.SelectedValue,
    .UserGroup = CmbUserGroup.SelectedValue,
    .Owner = CurrentUser,
    .Enabled = True
}

' Add new user to the model
Db.Users.Add(NewUser)
```

See the count of users before and after adding

[image]

The first user that is added is **NewUser** object and the second one is **CurrentUser**!!!

Is this a bug?

Comment: Do you really want one entity in the context to be owned by another that isn't? How would that make sense?

Comment: Owner = Creator. Each entity has an owner that shows which user created it. This also happens for user entity.

Comment: OK, but are you going to provide answers to the questions I actually asked?

Comment: As I said, yes. I need to add a 'User' entity that has a 'Owner' propertyof type 'User'

Comment: So not answering then.

Comment: is the currentUser also a 'User' object? and does it exist in your context? otherwise you arer adding 2 objects to the context. the user itself and the 'CurrentUser' object

Comment: Current user is a property of User object. Then how can I implement this? I still think that this is a bug.

Comment: Hi! Having similar bug. I add an object and I get two, but I do not see the second object in my database table?! It is missing the Id and I can only retrieve/see the second object in a datagrid. context.ipostcard_addresses.Add(newaddress);
                        context.SaveChanges();